# IllegalStateException on opening options menu

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-optionsmenu

I got a weird behaviour with the options menu in one of my activities: when the user navigates away (but not finishing it) from the activity and back again and then invokes the options menu, the app crashes with an `IllegalStateException`. The exception only throws if the menu has been shown before leaving the activity.
It seems that not my code is causing this. The activity is a `ListActivity`. In the first place I thought my `Adpater` might cause this, but the exception comes from the internals where the options menu (panel) is created.

To make thinks even weirder, this isn't happening on all devices. Currently I can only reproduce this on a  HTC Sensation with Android 4.0.3.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3345)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3196)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanel(PhoneWindow.java:614)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUpPanel(PhoneWindow.java:884)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUp(PhoneWindow.java:1557)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1884)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3407)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3380)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2523)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Creating the options menu looks pretty basic (and the same like in all other of my activities, which don't make any problems):

```java
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.message_thread, menu);
    return true;
 }

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuItemToContacts);
    // enable/disable some items ...

    return true;
}
```

The corresponding menu.xml looks as the following.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuItemSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_einstellungen"
        android:title="@string/settings">
    </item>
    <!-- some more elements in the exact same style -->
</menu>
```

I already tried a lot (especially with creating and preparing the menu). The biggest problem is, that I cannot catch the exception anywhere because it's bubbling up from some `View`.

**Hints and possible work-a-rounds are much apprechiated!!1!**

---

In my `Adapter` I actually do some view stuff, but I think I'm being carefull with adding views. Furthermore, the exception doesn't include any trace to my classes, so I'm in doubt that it's really the adapter causing this.

```java
private class ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout stateList;
    // more view elements
}

private class ChildContainer {

    public void bind(ViewHolder holder) {
        // prepare listeners and save reference to holder
    }

   /**
     * Populates the view
     */
    private void fillStateLists() {
       // ...
       if (convertView == null) {
        try {
            this.holder.stateList.addView(view);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            if (view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
            }
            this.holder.stateList.addView(view);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

My `ViewHolder` gets invoked in the `Adapter`s `bindView()`:

```
final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
final long viewID = getItemId(cursor.getPosition());
final ChildContainer child = this.childContainers.get(viewID);
child.bind(holder);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some (stupid) reason `onSaveInstanceState` got called in `onStop` to save the scroll position of the list view. Additionally `onRestoreInstanceState` got called in `onStart`.

Taking a look into the super implementations reveals that the view hierarchy states get saved and restored. The additional calls propably caused invalid states especially for the options panel and when the panel was needed again everything fell apart.

Removing those calls and making sure that saving my states happens only in `onSaveInstanceState` and restoring respectivly in `onRestoreInstanceState` fixed the issue.

Never break the Activity lifecycle! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not any problem in creating the option menu. It can be there in the Adapter code.

Comment: Actually I do some view-adding in the adapter (see edit). But I do catch `IllegalStateException`s. Furthermore, I'd expect that the exception would contain some traces to my classes.

Comment: you are taking the holder reference from this by usually holder is kep as tag on the convertView. Check this in your code.

Comment: I guess it's more complicated ;-)
The holder is comming from the view tag. Each element in the list has a `ChildContainer` which is store in `LongSparseArray`.